# Apollo federation PUSH command to skip SSLValidation

Tags: ssl, graphql, push, apollo, federated

I'm trying to push GraphQL schema to Apollo federation by using HTTPS serviceURL and endpoint. But I am getting the following error. How can I achieve this by skipping the SSL validation in Node.js?

> reason: write EPROTO 4454038976:error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version
> number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/r …
> FetchError: request to https://localhost:8080/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 4454038976:error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version
> number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
> Code: EPROTO

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a resolution to this?  thank you

Comment: @BryanAneux yes, see below solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing the following steps:

1. Add **NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0** in **.env** file of federated service
2. Run the command **export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0**
3. Run Apollo **Push** Command  file of federated service